# Move a class from one element to another in list of elements

Tags: jquery, arrays

I would like to set `active` class from one element to another in list of elements. In order to get the list of elements I've used below code:

```
$(document).on('click touchstart', 'button.previouslecture', function () {    
    var allchapters = $('div.chapter');
    console.log(allchapters);

    // todo: set previous lecture as active

});

$(document).on('click touchstart', 'button.nextlecture', function () {    
    var allchapters = $('div.chapter');
    console.log(allchapters);

    // todo: set next lecture as active

});
```

And this code returns below result on console:

[image]

Now, how do I write `jQuery` code to move `active` class to previous or next element in the list of elements.

**Update**

Here's sample HTML Code:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li class="mb-2 section">
        <a href="#sectionopen_@item.Unit.Id" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
            Something
        </a>
        <ul class="list-group collapse" id="sectionopen_@item.Unit.Id">
            <li>
                <div class="chapter active">
                    <a href="#" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        Something
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="chapter">
                    <a href="#" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        Something
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="chapter">
                    <a href="#" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        Something
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="mb-2 section">
        <a href="#sectionopen_@item.Unit.Id" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
            Something
        </a>
        <ul class="list-group collapse" id="sectionopen_@item.Unit.Id">
            <li>
                <div class="chapter">
                    <a href="#" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        Something
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="chapter">
                    <a href="#" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        Something
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="chapter">
                    <a href="#" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        Something
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="chapter">
                    <a href="#" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        Something
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="mb-2 section">
        <a href="#sectionopen_@item.Unit.Id" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
            Something
        </a>
        <ul class="list-group collapse" id="sectionopen_@item.Unit.Id">
            <li>
                <div class="chapter">
                    <a href="#" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        Something
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="chapter">
                    <a href="#" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        Something
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="mb-2 section">
        <a href="#sectionopen_@item.Unit.Id" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
            Something
        </a>
        <ul class="list-group collapse" id="sectionopen_@item.Unit.Id">
            <li>
                <div class="chapter">
                    <a href="#" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        Something
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="chapter">
                    <a href="#" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        Something
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="chapter">
                    <a href="#" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        Something
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you share the HTML?

Comment: @smoksnes html code added in question, however i wanted solution which is DOM structure independent.

Comment: you can give each item an id `n sequence` then parse the id as number & do `$.('#5').setAttr()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Moved the declaration outside the button
- Used a counter
- Gave the buttons the same class and test on ID

```js
$(function() {
  var $allChapters = $('div.chapter'),
    cnt = 0;
  $(document).on('click touchstart', 'button.lecture', function() {
    $allChapters.eq(cnt).removeClass("active");
    cnt += $(this).is("#previouslecture") ? -1 : 1;
    if (cnt<0) cnt=0; // or set to $allChapters.length-1 to wrap
    if (cnt>=$allChapters.length) cnt--; // or set to 0 to wrap
    $allChapters.eq(cnt).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.active { border:1px solid black }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="previouslecture" class="lecture">Prev</button>
<button type="button" id="nextlecture"     class="lecture">Next</button>
<ul class="list-unstyled">
  <li class="mb-2 section" data-id="@item.Unit.Id">
    <a href="#sectionopen_@item.Unit.Id" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
            Something
        </a>
    <ul class="list-group collapse" id="sectionopen_@item.Unit.Id">
      <li>
        <div class="chapter active">
          <a href="#" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        Something
                    </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="chapter">
          <a href="#" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        Something
                    </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="chapter">
          <a href="#" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        Something
                    </a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="mb-2 section" data-id="@item.Unit.Id">
    <a href="#sectionopen_@item.Unit.Id" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
            Something
        </a>
    <ul class="list-group collapse" id="sectionopen_@item.Unit.Id">
      <li>
        <div class="chapter">
          <a href="#" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        Something
                    </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="chapter">
          <a href="#" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        Something
                    </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="chapter">
          <a href="#" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        Something
                    </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="chapter">
          <a href="#" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        Something
                    </a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="mb-2 section" data-id="@item.Unit.Id">
    <a href="#sectionopen_@item.Unit.Id" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
            Something
        </a>
    <ul class="list-group collapse" id="sectionopen_@item.Unit.Id">
      <li>
        <div class="chapter">
          <a href="#" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        Something
                    </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="chapter">
          <a href="#" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        Something
                    </a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="mb-2 section" data-id="@item.Unit.Id">
    <a href="#sectionopen_@item.Unit.Id" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
            Something
        </a>
    <ul class="list-group collapse" id="sectionopen_@item.Unit.Id">
      <li>
        <div class="chapter">
          <a href="#" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        Something
                    </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="chapter">
          <a href="#" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        Something
                    </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="chapter">
          <a href="#" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        Something
                    </a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Currently, I would say that this is the most elegant solution.

Comment: This is most quick solution, and best in code. Thanks @mplungjan this helped.

Comment: I decided to use this solution, will a very little change in id selector to class selector, thanks.

Comment: I prefer the updated code. Give the buttons the same class and test on ID - You did not post the button codes so I improvised

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).on('click touchstart', 'button.previouslecture', function () {    
    var all = $('div.chapter');
    var index = all.index(all.filter('.active'))
    if(index == 0)
    {
        alert('Already first');
                return;

    }
    
    var active = $('div.chapter.active');
    var next = all.eq(index-1);

    next.addClass('active')
    active.removeClass('active')

});

$(document).on('click touchstart', 'button.nextlecture', function () {    
    var all = $('div.chapter');
    var active = $('div.chapter.active');    
    var index = all.index(all.filter('.active'))
    if(index == all.length-1)
    {
        alert('Already last');
        return;
    }
    
    var active = $('div.chapter.active');
    var next = all.eq(index+1);
    
    next.addClass('active')
    active.removeClass('active')

});
```

```css
.active{
background-color:gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li class="mb-2 section" data-id="@item.Unit.Id">
        <a href="#sectionopen_@item.Unit.Id" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
            Something
        </a>
        <ul class="list-group collapse" id="sectionopen_@item.Unit.Id">
            <li>
                <div class="chapter ">
                    <a href="#" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        Something
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="chapter">
                    <a href="#" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        Something
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="chapter active">
                    <a href="#" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        Something
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="mb-2 section" data-id="@item.Unit.Id">
        <a href="#sectionopen_@item.Unit.Id" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
            Something
        </a>
        <ul class="list-group collapse" id="sectionopen_@item.Unit.Id">
            <li>
                <div class="chapter">
                    <a href="#" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        Something
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="chapter">
                    <a href="#" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        Something
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="chapter">
                    <a href="#" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        Something
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="chapter">
                    <a href="#" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        Something
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="mb-2 section" data-id="@item.Unit.Id">
        <a href="#sectionopen_@item.Unit.Id" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
            Something
        </a>
        <ul class="list-group collapse" id="sectionopen_@item.Unit.Id">
            <li>
                <div class="chapter">
                    <a href="#" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        Something
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="chapter">
                    <a href="#" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        Something
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="mb-2 section" data-id="@item.Unit.Id">
        <a href="#sectionopen_@item.Unit.Id" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
            Something
        </a>
        <ul class="list-group collapse" id="sectionopen_@item.Unit.Id">
            <li>
                <div class="chapter">
                    <a href="#" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        Something
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="chapter">
                    <a href="#" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        Something
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="chapter">
                    <a href="#" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        Something
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<button class="previouslecture">Previous</button>
<button class="nextlecture">Next</button>
```

Comment: all chapters are not under single list, pls check my code. i need DOM structure free/independent solution.

Comment: This worked like, just copied and paste in my source code, thank you so much.